# Block operation until method return C# and Skype

Tags: c#, delegates, skype

I have this issue. I want to make calls to various numbers through Skype. In order for this to work I have to place a call and then wait for this call to complete (it is dropped upon receiving a ringing tone) before I make another call.

The problem is that although I try to do it asynchronously and wait for the function to return I get an error indicating that the next call begins before the first completes. Here is the code:

```
class Program
{
  static Skype skype = new Skype();
  static String[] numbers = new String[] { "phonenumber1", "phonenumber2" };
  public delegate void TCall(Call pCall, TCallStatus Status);

static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        ((_ISkypeEvents_Event)skype).AttachmentStatus += OnAttachmentStatus;


        skype.Attach(8);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void OnAttachmentStatus(TAttachmentStatus status)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("attacment: " + skype.Convert.AttachmentStatusToText(status));


        // only after this apiAttachSuccess can we do much anything
        if (status == TAttachmentStatus.apiAttachSuccess)
        {
            foreach (string number in numbers)
            {
                Call pCall = skype.PlaceCall(number);
                TCall theCall = OnCallStatus;
                IAsyncResult ar = theCall.BeginInvoke(pCall, pCall.Status, null, null);
                theCall.EndInvoke(ar);
                while (!ar.IsCompleted)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(200);
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Next Call Please");
            }

        }
    }

    static void OnCallStatus(Call pCall, TCallStatus Status)
    {
        //Thread.Sleep(2000);

        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        while (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds<=5000)
        {
            if (pCall.Status == TCallStatus.clsRinging)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ringing");
                break;

            }
        }
        return;



    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Rather than blocking the current thread until the callback completes, have the current thread just be done at that point and do whatever needs to be done in the callback that is called when the call completes.  That's how asynchronous programming works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're calling EndInvoke too early. Trying moving it after the while loop.

Alternatively, you can use a wait handle like this

```
IAsyncResult ar = theCall.BeginInvoke(pCall, pCall.Status, null, null);
ar.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();  //Blocks until complete
theCall.EndInvoke(ar);
```